# Facebook Send to Messenger button doesn't render

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to show a Send to Messenger button and I'm on it for a very long time already.

I didn't create any webhooks yet as I just want to have the Send to Messenger button to appear as a beginning, maybe this can be the reason?

Page ID: taken from Page "About" section. 
App ID: taken from the app dashboard.

Code:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1305XXXXXXXX',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v3.0'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<br>

<div class="fb-send-to-messenger"
  messenger_app_id="1305XXXXXXXX" 
  page_id="1705XXXXXXXX"
  color="blue"
  size="large" >
</div>
```

I'm indeed the Administrator of the app and have an active session on FB.

Domain is set in all the possible places in the Page and App settings.(Whitelisted Domains, Site URL, App Domains)

Comment: It says right on top of the documentation page, _“The "Send to Messenger" plugin is used to trigger an authentication event to your webhook.”_ ... so now guess how much sense that can possibly make, if you didn’t even properly set up a messenger bot yet?

Comment: You're right. I just did scroll thru 20 full-page documentation pages today so I guess I just didn't read carefully enough. Thanks.